# Exists a easy way to play MP4 videos on Android 1.5? (compatible with higher versions of the SO)

Tags: android, mp4

I need to play a short MP4 video when my app starts.

I'm searching info about how to load mp4 videos but I can't find the way to do it on Android 1.5

My app should be compatible from Android 1.5 to 4.0

Exists a easy way to play MP4 videos on Android 1.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VideoView. Create object and set uri to video. If you are trying to play video from res folder use this URI pareser:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.pac.myapp/raw/video_name");
```

Where com.pac.myapp is your app package name and video_name is name of your video file under raw folder.

After you get uri use it with videoview function

```
setVideoURI(Uri uri)
```

If you want video to start playing after activity is visible, override onvisibilistychange function of activity, and start playing as you get true from function parameter.

**EDIT**

```
VideoView view=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
Uri videPath=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapp/raw/1");
view.setVideoUri(videoPath);
```

That should work, if you get exception please paste it here. I will gladly help.

Comment: i'm trying to do with this code from android developers: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html

I have the video stored on the assets folder (must be there), how can i specify the path to the video on the assets folder? (1.mp4)

Comment: im trying to do with your way but im stuck... did you have a full code example to do it?

Comment: You have to put video into raw under res not to assets.